# Change startup form under Visual Studio 2010 Professional for C++ Windows Form Application

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010

For some reason, I can't seem to find a way to do this:  changing the start up form for C++ Windows Application under Visual Studio Professional 2010.  As many websites have suggested that go into Project\properties\Application\startup from etc.  My problem was that I could not find the "Application" or Startup Form anywhere under Project\Properties.

What did I miss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the C++ IDE, it doesn't have these kind of goodies.  You are supposed to change the code yourself.  Double-click the .cpp file that has the same name as your project in the Solution Explorer window.  Locate the main() function and change the Application.Run() call:

```
// Create the main window and run it
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());    // Change "Form1" here
```

Comment: That was it.  Also you will need to replace the Form1.h in the #include statement to your "new form".h in the same .cpp file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First, you check the Startup objects setting in your project's properties:
[image]

Than, you go to Program.cs and change the default here:

[image]

Replace Form1 with any other form you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The C++ IDE doesn't have an Application tab in the Project + Properties screen.  Which is what confuzzles the OP.

Comment: But the idea is that you need to modify in the code the startup object, too.