# How can I choose startup object in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

There are three cpp files and if I start debug, an error message appears: "Choose startup object."

So I clicked 'Current document' but nothing has changed.

Some peoply say do right click on solution and go to 'properties', but I can't find the 'properties' menu...
How can I choose startup object?

Comment: Which VS version did you use? Like The Apache's suggestion, please make sure that you set the correct project as the startup project, generally we could right click the whole solution(not the cpp file or the project itself) in solution explorer, and visit the property window. Of course, please also make sure that it is not the code issue like this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525679/change-startup-form-under-visual-studio-2010-professional-for-c-windows-form-a

Answer (score 6):

Under the solutions explorer, find the name of your project. Right click and you will find **set as startup project** command.

Comment: I'm not seeing that I'm trying to set folder as my startup item but it's not working... I mean my peers showed me that they did the setup on their machine but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

With Visual Studio IDE 2019 on MAC, legacy method of setting up a startup object for C# project has been changed.

If you are C# beginner and have built console project for learning core concept, then there might be a situation, where you may write main() method in each .cs code file to evaluate concepts. so here are below steps to be followed in order to change (.cs) startup object for debugging your intended .cs file using visual studio IDE 2019 on MAC :

1. Go to project solution hierarchy
2. Select (.cs) file, which set to be startup object.
3. press Control+leftClick from keyboard and select 'Properties' option.
4. In 'Properties' windows, select 'Build action' attribute and set its value to 'complie'
5. and change same value to 'none' for other .cs files, which are not to be set startup object.

As in result, build will be successful and your program will run in command line interface.

Comment: I'm not getting results from this on WIndows, VS 2022. I note that "Startup object" is a field in the project properties, but I can't see how to control the contents of its dropdown.

Comment: Same here, just not an option in VS2022

Answer (score 2):

First, the question mentions the startup **object**, not **project**.

In my Visual Studio 2022 on Windows, my WPF project's properties contain a field "Startup object" which can be either (Not set) or the App.xaml(.cs). I wanted to control execution more than that, by changing the project to a console application and setting Program.cs as the startup object.

I managed this by editing the project XML. I had this line:

```
<StartupObject></StartupObject>
```

And now I have this one:

```
<StartupObject>Wpf.Program</StartupObject>
```

After this change, I see Wpf.Program as the selected option in the project's properties.

I found this answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/advanced#mainentrypoint-or-startupobject).

Comment: I switch from a class library to console app and lost the startup. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also access advanced startup options by going into `Main Menu` -> `Project` -> `Set up startup projects` dialog (or launch it from context menu for solution item in Solution Explorer).

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me when I tried to write c++ on a "visual studio solution".
Make sure to select (or install and select) the correct project type when creating it.